# hibernate cascade between two schemas

Tags: hibernate, schema, cascade, transient

we have an application with links between entities on differents schemas:

```
Entity A (from schema 1) --@OneToMany(cascade=MERGE)--> Entity B (from schema 2).
```

Sometimes we have a problem with cascade type merge when Merging A in this case:

```
A = getAbyId(id)
A.setB( new B() )
merge(A)
```

here is the error:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance – 
save the transient instance before flushing
```

this error refers object B as the unsaved entity.

I thought that with cascade TYPE = Merge, it should handle in the right order to save of B then A.

Should we handle this manually?

thank you